# Python Dictionary key is different but values are same

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, key, key-value

I have a problem with python dictionary. My code is like this:

```
import os
import xlrd

working_dir = os.getcwd()

source_wb = xlrd.open_workbook(working_dir+'/4G_CA_Traffic.xlsx')
source_ws = source_wb.sheet_by_name('Subreport 1')

rownum=(source_ws.nrows-1)
colnum=(source_ws.ncols-1)
cline=0
act_cline=0

ARRAY = {}
temp = {}

while(cline<rownum):
    temp["CELLNAME"]=source_ws.cell_value(cline+1,3)
    key = temp["CELLNAME"]
    ARRAY[key]=temp
    cline=cline+1

for key in ARRAY.keys():    
    print(key+"\t"+ARRAY[key]["CELLNAME"])
```

At the end `key` and `ARRAY[key]["CELLNAME"]` values should be the same but they are not.

Python give's a result like below:

```
C:\Python36\python.exe C:/PROJELER/PYTHON/KPI/deneme_aa.py

LK738825O415479872  LY140715O147613031

LK730215O415479771  LY140715O147613031

LB587325O815408912  LY140715O147613031

LK706735O545513813  LY140715O147613031

L0587425O545492412  LY140715O147613031

LM362625O415488912  LY140715O147613031

LK797135O415481913  LY140715O147613031

LK950525O415486512  LY140715O147613031
```

Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: This question would attract more interested readers (and probably a more favorable score) if you rewrote it as a [MCVE] that we can actually test and execute. For starters, we don't have the files you are opening. Can you reproduce the same problem without file access or with short dummy files that you include in your question? Second, there are a couple of lines in the code that don't seem to have much to do with the problem, try to shorten the code until you arrive at the smallest version that produces the problem. Third, comments in the code would be nice such that we can have a clue what

Comment: the heck is supposed to be going on. It's possible that someone will post a minor fix in a second, but I can't be bothered to try because of all the flaws in the question.

Comment: Just a couple of pointers: if you're using dictionaries: please don't name the variable array, it's just confusing everybody. Also you can iterate over dicts with `for key,value in dict.items():` which makes things `ARRAY[key]["CELLNAME"]` a simple `value['CELLNAME']` ;>

Comment: `key` and `ARRAY[key]["CELLNAME"]` are *not* the same. Only, all `ARRAY[key]["CELLNAME"]` are the same, but this depends on data you don't show us...

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a mutable dictionary called `temp` to `ARRAY[key]` therefore the value you get is the latest state of `temp`. To fix this:

```
while(cline<rownum):
    temp["CELLNAME"]=source_ws.cell_value(cline+1,3)
    temp["SITENAME"] = source_ws.cell_value(cline + 1, 4)
    temp["LAC"] = source_ws.cell_value(cline + 1, 5)
    temp["CELLID"] = source_ws.cell_value(cline + 1, 6) 
    ARRAY[cell_name] = dict(temp)  # Makes a new copy of `temp`
    cline=cline+1
```

Comment: @sonerss I have updated the answer according to your second question, but please do not post an answer to ask a new question. This is not how things work here! You can update your question or start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote:

```
while cline < rownum :
    tmp = source_ws.cell_value(cline+1,3)
    ARRAY[tmp] = {"CELLNAME":tmp}
    cline += 1
```

ARRAY would be a dictionary, something like:

```
{"QWERTY":{"CELLNAME":"QWERTY"},
 "ASDFGH":{"CELLNAME":"ASDFGH"},
 "ZXCVBN":{"CELLNAME":"ZXCVBN"},
 ...,
 }
```

But since you assign temp, which it gets rewritten every line with the latest value...

```
#temp is:  {"CELLNAME":"LASTVAL"} 

{"QWERTY":temp,
 "ASDFGH":temp,
 "ZXCVBN":temp,
 ...,
 }
```

Hence all the values are identical (in this example, it would print `LASTVAL`).

Comment: Ok I got it ;) Thanks for your support